# How to add the content `...<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>` into the HTML link when using Angular 2 **routerLink**?

Tags: html, dom, angular, angular-ui-router

Just wanting to know how include `<span class="sr-only">(current)</span>` on my clicked active link when using Angular 2 `routerLink`?

Example:

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Registers</a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="/organizations">Organizations</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sources:
[Twitter Bootstrap > Accessibility > Skip navigation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#skip-navigation)
[ANgular 2 > ROUTING & NAVIGATION](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your component, you can add a method `isActiveLink` like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="/dashboard">
            Dashboard
            <span *ngIf="isActiveLink('/dashboard')" class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="">Registers</a>
    </li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="/organizations">
            Organizations
            <span *ngIf="isActiveLink('/organizations')" class="sr-only">(current)</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['app/app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  isActiveLink(link:string) {
    return this.router.isActive(link);
  }

  constructor(private router:Router) {}
}
```

Comment: Thanks @noémi-salaün, it works!!! Just missing `import { Router } from '@angular/router';` on top :-p

Answer (score 0):

If you want just mark actually active route, you can just add `routerLinkActive` to directive (you did this), it adding class `active` to anchor tag, so you can simply style active link in css. If you have something like :

```
<ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
    <li routerLinkActive="active">
        <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you can simply style it, using this:

```
nav-sidebar li:active {
   background-color: #00CAFE;
}
```

Comment: Hi @ulou, the answer of noémi-salaün worked better (http://stackoverflow.com/a/39812050/2334082), but thank you for your response.